# svg not sharp, but blurry

Tags: html, css, svg, blurry

[image]

For whatever reason these svg files, seems blurry, and not 100% sharp in all browsers. These are svg files, and are enclosed within elements that are scaled to pixels, in other words using px and not % - hence no browser bitmap errors.

Any idea as to why this is happening?

This is one of the svg files;

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 361.5 192.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 361.5 192.5;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:none;}
 .st1{fill:#FC5500;}
 .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st3{fill:#FB5500;}
</style>
<g>
 <path class="st0" d="M-9.4-6.3c126,0,252,0,378,0c0,68.7,0,137.3,0,206c-126,0-252,0-378,0C-9.4,131-9.4,62.4-9.4-6.3z"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M-0.2,112.1c0-8,0-15.9,0-24.4c112.3,0,224.3,0,336.7,0c0-29.4,0-58.4,0-87.7c8.4,0,16.4,0,25,0
  c0,46.8,0,93.7,0,140.6c-2.4-0.3-2.5-2.5-3.2-4c-3.7-9-10.3-15-19.3-18.5c-15.2-6-31.2-6.7-47.2-5.5c-7.8,0.6-15.6,1.5-23.1,4.1
  c-24.8,8.7-33.9,38-18.3,59.2c5.8,7.8,14.5,10.9,23.4,13.4c2,0.6,4.9-0.1,5.6,3.1c-13.9,0-27.9,0-41.8,0
  c-8.1-5.7-14.1-13.6-21.4-20.2c-1.7-1.5-3.8-2.8-4.1-5.5c0.5-2.5,2.8-3.1,4.7-3.9c9.5-4.3,14.3-11.9,14.5-22.1
  c0.2-10.1-4.8-17.3-13.9-21.8c-8.5-4.2-17.6-5.3-26.7-5.5c-20.8-0.4-41.6-0.1-62.5-0.1c-1.7,0-3.3,0-4.8,0.8
  c-1.6,2.3-1.1,4.9-1.1,7.3c0,21.2,0,42.3,0,63.5c0,2.6,0.5,5.4-1.7,7.6c-32,0-64,0-96.1,0c-3.2-6.9-1.5-13.8-0.9-20.2
  c3.1-2.6,6-2.3,8.8-2.3c12.7-0.1,25.3,0,38-0.1c7.8-0.1,15.3-1.6,22.2-5.3c17.8-9.6,18.8-33.3,1.7-44.3c-8.9-5.7-19.1-6.7-29.3-6.9
  c-19.3-0.3-38.7,0.1-58-0.1C4.6,113.4,2,113.8-0.2,112.1z"/>
 <path class="st2" d="M120.6,192.5c0-26.6,0-53.3,0-80.7c29.5,1.5,58.7-2.6,87.6,2.2c13.5,2.2,24.2,9.5,24.9,25.1
  c0.6,14.2-6.8,23.1-20.2,27c8.3,8.8,16.5,17.6,24.7,26.4c-11.2,0-22.5,0-33.7,0c-4-1.4-6-5-8.7-7.9c-12.1-13.2-6.6-11-23.7-11.2
  c-5.5-0.1-10.9,0-16.4,0c-2,0-4-0.2-6,1c-1.5,3.5-0.5,7.4-0.8,11.1c-0.2,2.4,0.3,5-1.7,7.1C138,192.5,129.3,192.5,120.6,192.5z"/>
 <path class="st2" d="M203.8,0.7c-4.9,6.4-10,13.1-15.2,20c-18.4,0-36.7,0-55,0c-4.1,0-9-0.2-8.9,5.9c0,6.1,4.8,5.9,9,6
  c16.8,0.2,33.7-0.4,50.5,0.6c12.5,0.7,22.4,6.1,22.6,20.9c0.2,14.6-7.3,24.7-22.5,25.3c-28.5,1.2-57.1,0.3-85.9,0.3
  c5-6.5,10.1-13.2,15.3-20c19.3,0,38.4,0.1,57.6-0.1c4.4,0,11.3,1.9,11.3-5.3c0.1-7.7-7-5.4-11.6-5.5c-16.1-0.4-32.4,0.3-48.4-0.9
  c-13-1-21.7-8.1-21.9-22.5c-0.2-14.9,8.5-23.6,22-24.3C149.5-0.2,176.6,0.7,203.8,0.7z"/>
 <path class="st2" d="M279.5,192.5c-31.5-9.3-41.2-22.1-36.9-48.9c2.8-17.6,15-26,31-29.7c18.9-4.4,38-4.4,57-0.2
  c15.1,3.4,26.5,11.3,31,27c0,7.6,0,15.2,0,22.9c-2.8,16.5-15.6,27.1-34.6,28.6c-1,0.1-2-0.2-2.9,0.3
  C309.1,192.5,294.3,192.5,279.5,192.5z"/>
 <path class="st2" d="M77.2,20.7c-17.1,0-33.9,0-51.1,0c0,3.2,0,6.3,0,9.8c20.5,0,41.1,0,62.9,0c-5.3,6.7-9.8,12.4-14.4,18.2
  c-16.2,0-32.1,0-48.5,0c0,3.6,0,7,0,10.8c22,0,44.1,0,67.6,0c-5.9,7.7-11,14.5-16,21.1c-26,0-51.6,0-77.6,0C0,53.7,0,27,0,0
  c30.7,0,61.4,0,93,0C87.6,7.1,82.5,13.8,77.2,20.7z"/>
 <path class="st2" d="M-0.2,112.1c25.3,0.1,50.6-0.4,75.9,0.7c20.2,0.9,32.8,13.2,32.7,29.5c-0.1,16.5-13.5,28.5-34.1,29.3
  c-16.3,0.6-32.6,0.1-49.7,0.1c0,7.4,0,14.1,0,20.9c-8.1,0-16.3,0-24.8,0C-0.2,165.6-0.2,138.8-0.2,112.1z"/>
 <path class="st2" d="M233.3-0.2c18.6,0,37-0.5,55.3,0.1c21,0.7,34.6,13.1,34.6,30.5c0,17.4-13.8,29.5-35.4,30.1
  c-15.1,0.5-30.3,0.1-45.9,0.1c0,6.7,0,13.1,0,19.8c-8.6,0-16.6,0-25,0c0-13.4,0-26.6,0-40.7c22.6,0,45.3,0,68.1,0
  c5.2,0,10.8-0.6,12.4-6.2c2.6-9.1-3-12.6-11.1-12.7c-22.7-0.2-45.5-0.1-69.4-0.1C222.7,13.3,227.9,6.6,233.3-0.2z"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M146.7,192.5c0-6.8,0-13.6,0-20.8c13.2,0,26.1,0,39.7,0c5.6,6.6,11.6,13.7,17.6,20.8
  C184.9,192.5,165.8,192.5,146.7,192.5z"/>
 <path class="st3" d="M323.9,192.5c17.1-3.7,32.3-9.9,37.6-29c0,9.5,0,18.9,0,29C349,192.5,336.4,192.5,323.9,192.5z"/>
 <path class="st3" d="M145.8,150.8c0-5.7,0-11.4,0-17.1c17.9,0,35.6-0.2,53.3,0.2c4.4,0.1,7.8,3.1,7.7,8.3c-0.1,6-4.5,8.4-9.3,8.5
  C180.4,151,163.3,150.8,145.8,150.8z"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M302.2,173.1c-6-0.4-11.4-0.7-16.9-1.1c-12.8-1.1-18.4-8-18.1-20.9c0.3-12.7,7.6-17.4,19-18.6
  c11.1-1.1,22.3-1.2,33.4,0.1c11.3,1.3,17.2,7.1,17.3,19c0.1,11.8-5,18.7-16.7,20C314.1,172.4,307.9,172.7,302.2,173.1z"/>
 <path class="st3" d="M25.1,133c15.6,0,30.9-0.2,46.2,0.1c5.6,0.1,11.1,1.8,11.2,8.7c0.2,7.1-5.2,9.3-11.1,9.4
  c-15.3,0.3-30.6,0.1-46.3,0.1C25.1,145.5,25.1,139.6,25.1,133z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Which browsers exhibit the blurriness?

Comment: all I've tested, chrome, IE and fire

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want your SVG to be at its sharpest, then design it so that its shapes - especially the horizontal and vertical parts of the shapes - are on pixel boundaries.

For example, compare the following two examples:

```html
<svg width="50" height="50">
  <rect x="9.5" y="9.5" width="31" height="31"/>
</svg>

<svg width="50" height="50">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30"/>
</svg>
```

Here's what this looks like at 4X enlargement.[image]

Any time your shape passes through the middle of pixels, you will get grey pixels due to the anti-aliasing that 2D renderers use.

Comment: I have a logo in illustrator. How can i achieve such an output?

Comment: If you have control over the final display width and height, then make sure any horizontal or vertical edges are positioned at coordinates that will correspond to an pixel boundary in the final output.  If you don't have control of the final output size, then there is nothing you can really do (other than the less than ideal `crispEdges` approach). You'll just have to live with it. The good news is that 99.999% of your users won't notice, or won't care, that parts of the logo look a little blurry.

Comment: Why would this solve anything for svgs that are not predominantly horizontal and vertical boundaries?

Comment: As I said in my answer, for best results, try to arrange it so as many parts of your shape are coincident with pixel boundaries, and cut through the middle of as few pixels as possible.

Answer (score 16):

The response used a slightly modified code @Paul LeBeau

You can use the SVG attribute -  **shape-rendering =" crispEdges "** to disable browser anti-aliasing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

> **crispEdges**
>
> Indicates that the user agent shall attempt to emphasize the contrast
>   between clean edges of artwork over rendering speed and geometric
>   precision. To achieve crisp edges, the user agent might turn off
>   anti-aliasing for all lines and curves or possibly just for straight
>   lines which are close to vertical or horizontal. Also, the user agent
>   might adjust line positions and line widths to align edges with device
>   pixels.

```html
<svg width="50" height="50">
  <rect x="9.5" y="9.5" width="31" height="31" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/>
</svg>

<svg width="50" height="50">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30"/>
</svg>
```

The image is increased 4 times

[image]

No gray pixels are observed.

---

**Update 2019 by comments**

There is no universal, 100% solution to the pixelation problem.
Since the rendering depends on the installed operating system, its settings, the video card and which browser is used.

*You can use an integrated approach made up of all the answers of this topic:*

1. Use integer `svg` image coordinate values  by answer @Paul LeBeau

   If you take a finished image with fractional values, you can process
   it with [SVG optimizer](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)
2. Set the integer value of `viewBox`  by answer @AKX
3. Use the attribute `shape-rendering ="crispEdges"`

If a design change is possible, avoid contrasting border colors.

For example, use a dark gray color instead of a black and white combination or use shades of gray instead of a pure white background.

Comment: @Vincent Wen  I am pleased that it helped you

Comment: This works great for shapes that are rectangular and non-rotated, but as soon as diagonal lines or curves are introduced they become VERY pixelated.

Comment: @clayRay Added an answer to your comment

Comment: An update here: shape-rendering ="crispEdges" may help you but it's definitely not a final solution cause in some browser it may lead to really bad drawing.

I would suggest you may predefine add this option to some particular devices and browsers, but don't make it a normally option.

In the end, I think when you see blurry, it mostly device (eg: screen resolution ratio) related issue but not SVG and you may just accept it

Comment: Small addition: You can set the shape-rendering ="crispEdges" attribute on the main svg node

Comment: Even worse pixelation now.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the SVG on a page and it doesn't look really blurry to me.

However, you could try editing the viewbox to have an integer size -- i.e. turn `viewBox="0 0 361.5 192.5"` into `viewBox="0 0 362 193"` -- that might make a difference.

Comment: This was more or less my poroblem. My SVG circles, that go right to the edge of viewBox, were getting slightly cut-off in the browser, but not always. It depended on scale. Obviously it was rounding (up or down) of decimal viewBox values that accounted for the inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

it might be caused by use of borders and shadows in creation of the svg.
I avoid those myself as they are sometimes blurry.
Shadow if needed can be created as another path with transparency and offset.