# Blurry path edges in IE & Edge when SVG is preceded by an element not sized in pixels

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I am trying to draw a sharp rectangle using SVG `<path>`.

I have a problem that the top and bottom edge of the shape have an unexpected antialiasing when rendered in IE and Edge. The problem happens only if the `<path>` element is preceded by another element that has dimensions expressed in different unit than `px`.

The problem does not appear to `<div>` or SVG `<rect>` elements. Only SVG `<path>` seem to be affected.

I appreciate any help, how do I make the `<path>` render crisply without changeing the surrounding `<div>`s?

I can simulate the same problem with a simple SVG object and:

- a native button: https://jsfiddle.net/7btjcy18/
- a font sized with REM units: https://jsfiddle.net/ptzs71ba/

The following screenshot shows the problem. Chrome on the left, Edge on the right. On a zoom, you can see the blurry borders highlighted with the arrows.

[image]
[image]

```css
#div1 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">REM font size</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 0 0 L 300 0 L 300 100 L 0 100" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related with svg being in coordinates like 31.2 (not exactly on pixel line). I also found a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795431/svg-not-sharp-but-blurry). According to the accepted answer, you should design the svg to let its shapes are on pixel boundaries(especially the horizontal and vertical parts of the shapes).

> Any time your shape passes through the middle of pixels, you will get grey pixels due to the anti-aliasing that 2D renderers use.

I think it's the not integer value `1.2rem` which leads to the svg's coordinates not being on pixel line. I try with integer value and the issue is gone in IE and Edge:

```css
#div1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#div2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">REM font size</div>

<div id="div2"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="M 0 0 L 300 0 L 300 100 L 0 100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and for taking the screenshots. In fact, *there is the same difference on your screenshots` as on mine. You just need to zoom the screenshit in with a graphics software like Paint.NET. 

This is the close-up of your screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/IoV1lbd

Comment: @warpech I see. I researched again and you could check my updated answer.