# Antialias SVG text before filter is applied?

Tags: svg, text, svg-filters

SVG filters rasterize their source image, which means filtered text won't be anti-aliased, resulting in jagged edges.

Is there a workaround for this? Perhaps another filter can be used to emulate anti-aliasing, or maybe I can somehow anti-alias the text before the filter is applied?

Relevant Filter:

```
<filter id="f">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" result="blur" />
  <feColorMatrix
    in="blur"
    mode="matrix"
    values="1 0 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0
    1 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 15 -8"
    result="goo"
  />
  <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop" />
</filter>
```

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. Text elements provided as input to a filter will be anti-aliased before they're rasterized, and the filter preserves the anti-aliasing unless you're doing something to the alpha channel. What specific use case are you running into - please provide a minimal verifiable test case (aka code)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-water-yny8u – You will see jagged edges on the top `<text>`. It's more noticeable on lower PPI screens.

Answer (score 1):

Text elements provided as input to a filter will be anti-aliased before they're rasterized, and the filter preserves the anti-aliasing unless you're doing something to the alpha channel.

In this case, you ARE doing something to the alpha channel. That feColorMatrix filter is multiplying the alpha channel by 15 and then subtracting 8. This has the effect of converting any pixels that have less than 8/15th opacity to transparent - which strips most of the anti-aliasing.

If you want to smooth out the edges a little, you can add another feGaussianBlur with a 0.5 or 1 unit stdDeviation to the end. There are other methods to add back the anti-aliasing but it really depends on what you're trying to do. Since the current filter doesn't do anything - I assume the intention is to animate something?

(Also - that feColorMatrix should have `type='matrix'` not `mode='matrix'` - mode is only used in feBlend.)

Update: may as well add the various techniques to smooth the edges.

1. Original
2. Original with the crispy filter
3. #2 with a small blur tagged on at the end
4. #2 with a small blur tagged on but clipped to a one pixel perimeter
5. #2 with a small blur, but the low opacity part of the blur clipped to zero

```html
<svg width="1000px" height="1000px" >
  <filter id="f1">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" result="blur" />
  <feColorMatrix
    in="blur"
    mode="matrix"
    values="1 0 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0
    1 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 15 -8"
    result="goo"
  />
  <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop" />
</filter>
  
<filter id="f2">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" result="blur" />
  <feColorMatrix
    in="blur"
    mode="matrix"
    values="1 0 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0
    1 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 15 -8"
    result="goo"
  />
  <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop" />
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
</filter>
  
  <filter id="f3">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" result="blur" />
  <feColorMatrix
    in="blur"
    mode="matrix"
    values="1 0 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0
    1 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 15 -8"
    result="goo"
  />
  <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop" result="pre-final"/>
  <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1" result="base"/>
   <feGaussianBlur in="pre-final" stdDeviation="1" />
  <feComposite in2="base" operator="in" />
</filter>
  
  
<filter id="f4">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" result="blur" />
  <feColorMatrix
    in="blur"
    mode="matrix"
    values="1 0 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0
    1 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 15 -8"
    result="goo"
  />
  <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop" result="pre-final"/>
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 .7 .8 .9 1"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
  
  
  <text x="50" y="150" style="font-size: 160; font-weight: bold;">FILTERED </text>
    <text filter="url(#f1)" x="50" y="300" style="font-size: 160; font-weight: bold;">FILTERED </text>
      <text filter="url(#f2)" x="50" y="450" style="font-size: 160; font-weight: bold;">FILTERED </text>
        <text filter="url(#f3)" x="50" y="600" style="font-size: 160; font-weight: bold;">FILTERED </text>
         <text filter="url(#f4)" x="50" y="750" style="font-size: 160; font-weight: bold;">FILTERED </text> 

  </svg>
```

Comment: I'm animating the `stdDeviation` of the `feGaussianBlur`. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it out soon!

Comment: @Michael Mullany Thanks a lot for the theoretical part of the answer. Request to you: I would love to see practical examples demonstrating these effects of the filters.

Comment: Here are a couple of examples of what you can do: https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/1e5c1223cad2a0ad07cd0c5d31e141f0

Comment: @MichaelMullany Thank you so much for the examples.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a workaround for this? Perhaps another filter can be used to
> emulate anti-aliasing, or maybe I can somehow anti-alias the text
> before the filter is applied?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53794471/7394871) went into detail on the issue.

As a compromise solution, you can try:

1. Choose less contrasting colors for the color of letters and background
2. Apply the attribute `shape-rendering =" crispEdges"` to the font
3. Choose a font that renders sharper edges

For example, your chosen font `font-family =" cursive "` looks like this:

[image]

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="600" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  

<text  x="35" y="150" font-size="100px" fill="black" font-family="cursive"> HELLO </text>

</svg>
```

`font-family = "Monotype Corsiva"` looks better

[image]

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="silver" />
<text  x="35" y="120" font-size="100px" fill="#444444" shape-rendering="crispEdges" font-family="Monotype Corsiva"  > HELLO </text>

</svg>
```

### Applying an SVG filter to smooth jagged edges

- For the filter `feGaussianBlur` the parameters are selected (the last
  row of the matrix) `0 0 0 29 -1`
- For the filter  `feComposite` `operator="atop"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
<defs>
  <filter id="f">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" >
        
    </feGaussianBlur>   
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 29 -1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
</defs> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="silver" />
<text filter="url(#f)"  x="35" y="120" font-size="100px" fill="#444444" shape-rendering="crispEdges" font-family="Monotype Corsiva"  > HELLO </text>

</svg>
```

### Filter animation

> I'm animating the stdDeviation of the feGaussianBlur

As I understood from **@aleclarson**'s comment you want to animate the filter attribute

```
<animate attributeName="stdDeviation" begin="0s" dur="8s"
  repeatCount="indefinite" values="1;6;12;12;6;1;1" />
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
<defs>
  <filter id="f">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" >
   <animate attributeName="stdDeviation" begin="0s" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="1;6;12;12;6;1;1" />
    </feGaussianBlur>       
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 29 -1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
</defs> 

<text filter="url(#f)"  x="35" y="120" font-size="100px" fill="#111111" shape-rendering="crispEdges" font-family="Monotype Corsiva"  > HELLO </text>

</svg>
```

***Variant with value and operator = "xor"***

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
<defs>
  <filter id="f">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" >
   <animate attributeName="stdDeviation" begin="0s" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="1;6;12;12;6;1;1" />
    </feGaussianBlur>       
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 29 -1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="xor"/>
        </filter>
</defs> 

<text filter="url(#f)"  x="35" y="120" font-size="100px" fill="#111111" shape-rendering="crispEdges" font-family="Monotype Corsiva"  > HELLO </text>

</svg>
```