# Why logo is losing its quality in iPhone but not on other devices?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am working on a Next.js project that faced this problem. I have a logo that loses its quality when I open the website on my iPhone but not on other devices. Did anyone face this problem? How can I solve it?

My code:

```
<div className="flex items-center">
   <Link href="/" className="flex items-center">
     <img
        src="/assets/img/navbar_logo.svg"
        alt="logo"
        className="md:w-[115px] md:h-[65px] w-[90px] h-[44px]"
     />
   </Link>
 </div>
```

[The website](https://gm-direct-hire-website-front-end.vercel.app/)

Note: I used the HTML `<img>` tag instead of the Next.js Image component to show the real quality of the image. I know the Next.js Image component has some properties like `quality` for this, but it was not showing the real quality.

These are images that were taken on a Samsung phone and a iPhone.
[image: Samsung]
[image: iPhone]

Comment: Isn't it just about the size of the screen?

Comment: No, it is not because of that.

Comment: I confirm that the img has lost quality on my real iPhoneSE, but not on Windows10 Edge inspect facility emulating iPhone.

Comment: Don't have an iPhone to test on, but [here's one possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795431/svg-not-sharp-but-blurry#53794471) or CSS `image-rendering` property is another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your svg file has a png file embedded in it. You would be much better off adding the logo as a png as it appears by embedding the file inside a svg it is losing quality.

This is the image extracted from the svg and it is high resolution: [image: Extracted Image]